# Reading and writing XLSM spreadsheet containing macros in java

Tags: java

**I am getting following exception while reading `XLSM` spreadsheet excel file in java** :

*org.apache.poi.POIXMLException:        org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Package should      contain a content type part [M1.13]*

```
    //My Code Look like
         String source="test.xlsm";
        File file = new File("D:\\file\\"+source);
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file,false);
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        if(file.exists()){
          **Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fin); // While Reading time i am getting exception here**
          XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(1);
        }
```